# Recommendation for Hypergraph DBMS with visual editor (or at least viewer)?

Tags: user-interface, hypergraph

Can anyone point me in a promising direction or to a specialized community? I would like to create a graph representing domain knowledge with the following requirements:

1. allow true hypergraph: native reification = statements about statements = n-ary relationships = sequences of more than 3 vertices (subject-predicate-object logic not sufficient, modelling a hyperedge as vertex with two edges over-complicated).
2. result can be accesses / queried as semantic data (URI or similar, query by SPARQL, GRAQL, Gremlin or the like)
3. server-based / multiple user contributions of vertices + edges (no desktop system like non-web Protege).
4. graphic editor available for creating, developing, and viewing the graph: Content to be generated by non-IT/graph specialists who will understand visual representation of semantic graphs, but cannot reliably formulate code. Ready to install, not as API/ library to code it myself (I am no / have no web developer).
5. As a fallback to the above, visual client for visualization of the results and exploration of the graph available (simple text commands to add new objects and relations).
6. If a class structure / schema is required, it should be kept highly generic (The schema is the content to be developed collaboratively, primary use is to describe a domain, not to store big data).
7. Should be Open Source, or at least permanently free for academic use.

I am no IT-specialist and have limited insights into graphDBMS, but am willing to dig into it, so here is what I have researched so far:

1. web-Protege: no hypergraph, but visual editing and exploration
2. Neo4J: no hypergraph, but with bloom visual exploration (more or less visually supported editing)
3. grakn: hypergraph with visual viewer workbase, but all navigation and editing per text commands, limited function for community edition, proprietary format (more for internal use than semantic web)
4. HypergraphDB: hypergraph, open source, no visual editing - in general, I do not understand how to manipulate data with a client
5. Cayley Graph: no info on hyperhraph capability found, no graphic client found
6. TitanDB => Janusgraph: no info on hypergraph capability found, no graphic client found.
7. MS GraphEngine (formerly Trinity): supposedly hypergraph possible, but hardly any information on details / features / visual clients.
8. Hyper-X: supposedly hypergraph possible, but no further detailed info found.
9. I found the generic viewers linkurious (commercial), Gephi and Cytoscape (both open source), but not what GraphDBMS they can connect to and whether you can edit with them. Some seem to be local clients (I'd prefer to offer a web-based access, but I know I will have to live with compromises).